# nonexistence of a sufficient statistic

Tags: estimation, estimators, sufficient-statistics, point-estimation

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be a random sample from a [$\Gamma(\theta,\theta)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) distribution. Then 
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i;\theta) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\theta)^n\theta^n}(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i)^{\theta-1}e^{-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\theta}},
$$
which cannot be factored as in [Fisher–Neyman factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic). In particular, neither $\prod_i X_i$ nor $\sum_{i} X_i$ is a sufficient statistic.

Can we conclude that a sufficient statistic does not exist in this case?

Comment: The sample itself is always a sufficient statistic, so no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ and the vector of order statistics $(X_{(1)},X_{(2)},\ldots,X_{(n)})$ are trivial sufficient statistics for any continuous distribution indexed by a parameter.

For the Gamma distribution in question, a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ is simply $\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n X_i,\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right)$ by the Factorization theorem. So in some cases where you make both parameters equal (or make one parameter a function of the other) in a two-parameter distribution, you will get a two-dimensional sufficient statistic for a one-dimensional parameter.